# My Air Plant (Kalanchoe Pinnata) is attacked, how do I save it?

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, diseases

My  Air Plant ([Kalanchoe Pinnata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalanchoe_pinnata)) is attacked by little green worm like insects which are eating its leaves.

Slowly one by one, all of the leaves are dropped by the plant, now it is left with just two leaves.

To save it, I had sprayed  a pest shield solution(diluted with water) that contains **Polyoxalate Phenol (80%)** and **Anionic Surfactant (20%)** but no improvement so far.

Images for diagnosis of the problem:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the complete problem is without a picture of the pest. However these observations may assist you:

- the most common insect pests of Kalanchoe are Mealybugs, aphids and brown scale. Each of these insects tends to hang around a plant they infest and should be visible in a picture.  Mealybug look like tufts of white cotton. Scale looks like light or dark brown bumps and aphids come in a range of colours and look like [this](https://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&site=imghp&q=aphids&oq=aphids)
- each of these pests does not produce any visible damage to the leaf as they live off the plant juices.  Scale and Aphids produce a sugary exudate which dries to leave sticky glossy areas underneath the plant.
- kalanchoe also suffer from [fungal and viral diseases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kalanchoe_diseases) which are a better match for what is shown in the pictures. The sunken areas of dead tissue with black spots that are apparently inside the leaf are more typical of a fungal disease, perhaps a [Cercospora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercospora)

Here are some things you can check for to decide what to do:

- has the plant been over watered or grown in low light? These factors encourage the triad of fungal/bacteria/virus problems
- if the plant is grown inside your house are any other plants showing problems? Pests move around faster than diseases.
- Could you have a pest and a disease problem?  This is not unheard of for a sick plant to be attacked on multiple fronts

You mention Polyoxalate Phenol as a pest control. I cannot find any references to this and would like to know more.  Most indoor pest problems can be dealt with by a mixture of dish soap heavily diluted with water.

This plant is tough and adaptable. So much so that it has naturalized and considered invasive in Asia, Pacific and the Caribbean. One solution for your problem is to remove a healthy leaf and place in a small pot with free draining soil.  They propagate easily and with good light you will have a similar plant in a short period of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for much efforts! Few points I would like you to tell: 1. I can see the little green-white worms, they are inside leaves (1-3 mm length) also in picture which are eating pulp of leaves. I will try to take zoomed snap. 2. It is not Aphids. 3. Plant is in sunlight and watered moderatetly daily. 4. No other plants nearby shows up such worms\disease. 5. Dont know much about Polyoxalate Phenol, need to ask the vendor, will update you on this. 6. Will try diluted soap solution. 7. I has already propogated nearby, I have moved it to other pot & is growing well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This little green worm is a caterpillar. It is presumably red pierrot and is going to eat away all your plant. It's typical host plant is Kalanchoe and it is an exceptional leaf miner. So it will stay in leaf and create a channel throughout the plant to feed and sustain itself.

You can still save your plant by starting on a new healthy cutting from the mother plant or simply submerging the plant in soap water for some time and killing the caterpillar accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).